# Replace Workbook link with new constructed workbook link vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change an excel workbook link, but by constructing a new workbook link using dates in cells (the naming convention is always the same, except that the date changes)

I know that to change an excel workbook link (using VBA), all I have to do is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink "c:\excel\book1.xls", _ 
 "c:\excel\book2.xls", xlExcelLinks
```

But what if I want to construct a new workbook link using different figures in cells?

This is what I have been trying:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink "part of file name" & Range("N2") & ".xlsx"", _
 "part of file name" & Range("N4") & ".xlsx"", xlExcelLinks
```

Range N2 is the previous week's date, and Range N4 is current week's dates.

But whenever I do this I get the following message "Compile error: Syntax error"

Any ideas on what I can do? Really want to be able to construct file name as it'll mean I can automate a LOT of what I do...lol

Thank you in advance for any guidance on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to include `"` in string you must double it, so:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink """part of file name" & Range("N2") & ".xlsx""", _
 """part of file name" & Range("N4") & ".xlsx""", xlExcelLinks
```

this was your error reason

Also you should refer to `.Value` property od `Range` object, and if cells you are using contains dates the safest way would be using `Format(Range("N4").Value, "yyyymmdd")`

Comment: Thank you,for the help - I made the changes as you mentioned, and they work, it turns out there is another problem -it's the way the filepaths are altered. It's an internal IT issue (the filepath changes each time - and I know I can use an ELSEIF to deal with this, but for now will just a copy and paste lol)

Comment: Oh sorry, still a newbie on here. Will do that now! Thank you